# Anaconda Navigator launch problem Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

Can't Open anaconda, when i tried from the promp this appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy_*init*_.py", line
> 204, in 
> from PySide import **version** as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line
> 6, in module
> from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py",
> line 22, in module
> from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils_*init*_.py",
> line 15, in module
> from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy_*init*_.py", line
> 210, in module
> raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found') qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

Comment: HI Joshua, can you be more specific? When has this error been shown? After updating anaconda? Is this the first time you open anaconda?

Comment: Hi im new with python programming, this was my 1st time with anaconda i ussualy use Pycharm, i installed and run it but it never openned, so i try to oppen it on the prompt and this shows up.

Comment: try maybe this two steps: 1) `conda update conda` 2) `conda update all`